WHERE clause pulling incorrect values
I am calling a table and looking to find null values. Where report_date is looking for TRUE and two other columns are looking for FALSE, I seem to be getting inflated numbers and I believe it is the order of operations after my WHERE clause.
SELECT DISTINCT
    "report_date",
    "department",
    "business_unit"
FROM
    "system"
WHERE 
    "report_date" IS TRUE
    AND "department" IS FALSE
    OR "business_unit" IS FALSE;

I was expecting just to see the null values listed where the conditions are met, but it seems now the report date is pulling FALSE values.

What type of SQL are you using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc), I've not come across a dialect that uses quotes for field names. It could be that you're getting unexpected results because it's comparing the string "report_date" to TRUE, not the field report_date.

I believe AND is higher precedence then OR, so the WHERE clause is grabbing any record where "business_unit" is false, regardless of the other two conditions.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

WHERE "report_date" AND FALSE IN ("department", "business_unit")

"report_date" is a column, ANSI/ISO SQL standard syntax - supported by most dbms's. And single quotes are for string literals, e.g. 'some words'.

Also, 'string literal' IS TRUE isn't valid, and expected to raise an exception.

as mentioned in a comment, dont "quote" column names, but also may be getting incorrect values due to the where clause having the OR.  Probably try something more like
SELECT DISTINCT
      report_date,
      department,
      business_unit
   FROM
      system
   WHERE 
       report_date IS TRUE
    AND ( department IS FALSE
       OR business_unit IS FALSE )

Notice (parenthesis) around the OR testing on department and business unit.

Looking at the WHERE clause, the precedence for the OR operator sometimes surprises people. For this code, it's as if you had written the clause like this:
WHERE 
    (report_date IS TRUE  AND department IS FALSE)
    OR
    business_unit IS FALSE

Which is clearly not what you want. Fix it by manually putting the parentheses  around the correct group:
WHERE 
    report_date IS TRUE
    AND (department IS FALSE  OR business_unit IS FALSE)

